# height 100% in flex

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I want to make the content div to fit 100% height. For some reason, the container div happen to be a flex item. Is that appropriate to set 100% height to a div within a flex item? or I should set the content div to be a flex item as well.

Also, the flex-direction part is confusing. column do not work, but row do. I suppose the flex-direction only effect on the flex item.

[jsfiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/nrvbLgs6/2/?utm_source=website&utm_medium=embed&utm_campaign=nrvbLgs6)

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="content">
      Hello there
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

.wrapper {
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: 20px;
  min-height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  /* change flex-direction from column to row will work */
  flex-direction: column;
}

.container {
  border: 1px solid green;
  padding: 20px;
  flex: 1;
}

.content {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: for future reference, use the tag *flexbox* and *css3* instead of flex to call the flex-man experts ;)

Comment: now you will get you answer within few minutes :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can overlap (nest)  flex boxes :

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

.wrapper {
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: 20px;
  min-height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  /* change flex-direction from column to row will work */
  flex-direction: column;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}

.container {
  display:flex;
  flex-direction: column;/* up to your needs */
  border: 1px solid green;
  padding: 20px;
  flex: 1;
}

.content {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  flex:1;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="content">
      Hello there
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

You may also mind the box-sizing properties to include borders and padding in size calculation.

Comment: box-sizing is sweet :)
My confusion is the flex-direction part. Since the green box is 100% height, then why the blue box within can not fit 100% height? Is it an anti-pattern to set 100% height within a flex-item, like the blue box within the green?

Comment: @arpeggie height:100% requires an height to be set on the parent to be calculated (it won't take any reference from min-height either), if none, then it is like 100% of null. Here, in the flexbox context, the thing to use would be the flex propertie. the shorthand flex:1; will do the job and  padiing, margin and borders will not mess it up. the container (.content) will fill fill the whole space avalaible. flex drection is here to tell to mind the height.

Comment: So flexbox context is totally different with the typical 100% height stuff, I get it. Still, I feel it weird when the container(.content) has some height, (even though that is calculated through flexbox context), while the div within cannot get that height for 100% properly.

Comment: @arpeggie it is one of the nice thing about flex, it is flexible and doesn't require fixed size values to be layed all over its container ;) ... totally what web media is about . have a nice day.

Comment: A ding for the use of the word 'imbricate', when 'overlap' would suffice and be more clearly understood.

Comment: @AntonyBooth thanks for my average english ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```css
.wrapper {
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: 20px;
  min-height: 100%;
  /* This set a precise value for the height */  
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  /* change flex-direction from column to row will work */
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

Comment: By setting 100% height will surely work, but when the content is longer than the 100% height of wrapper, then there will be some trouble.